# Do I use the axiom of choice when I construct a sequence that converge?

Tags: real-analysis, axiom-of-choice

Let $E$ closed and $x\in E$. I want to show there is a sequence that converges to $x$. I do as follow :

We have that $$E_n:=E\cap \left[x-\frac{1}{n},x+\frac{1}{n}\right]\neq \emptyset,$$
for all $n$. So, for all $n\in\mathbb N$, there is $x_n\in E_n$. Therefore $|x_n-x|<\frac{1}{n}\to 0$ when $n\to \infty $, and thus, $(x_n)$ is a sequence of $E$ that converge to $x$.

Did I used the Axiom of choice to construct $(x_n)$ ? If yes, how ? (because I didn't construct a choice function, did I ?)

Comment: Regardless of the axiom of choice, the statement you're trying to prove is *false as written*: take e.g. $E=[0,1]\cup\{7\}$ and $x=7$.

Comment: then $x_n=7$ for all $n$ work...

Comment: If you're allowing that, then your statement as written is **trivial** (and doesn't rely on closedness at all) - simply take $x_n=x$ for all $x$. Are you sure you've written what you intend to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The statement is trivially true, since the constant sequence $x_n=x$ converges to $x$. It's also been pointed out in a comment that if we exclude $x$ (as you may have intended to imply), then the statement is false.

However, the corresponding statement for open sets is true: If $E\subseteq\mathbb R$ is open and $x\in E$, then there is a sequence $\{x_n\}_n$ with $x_n\ne x$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$ that converges to $x$. One possible proof proceeds in analogy to your proof, so we can ask the same question about this.

You do use a choice function, and yes, you are using the axiom of choice. You know that there is *some* $x_n\in E_n$, but you don't have a specific one, and you're not specifying a way to choose one. Thus, you're assuming the existence of a choice function to choose one.

You can prove the same thing without using the axiom of choice, though. Since $E$ is open, there is some $n_0\in\mathbb N$ such that $x+\frac1n\in E$ for all $n\ge n_0$. This sequence lies in $E$ and converges to $x$, and you don't need to assume the existence of a choice function to define it.

*Update*:

On your last question: No, you didn't **construct** a choice function, you **assumed** that one existed. It's the other way around: If you **construct** a choice function, you don't need to use the axiom of choice. You use it when you **assume** the existence of a choice function without **constructing** one.